# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parsing, middleware

i am facing this problem on my JavaScript (node.js) web-app. I am trying to create a middleware to authenticate and register a user as an admin. The code doesn't return an error until i test it on postman and i get this error on console TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

Below is my middleware code

```
require('dotenv').config()
function isAdmin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body && req.body.pin) {
        const { pin } = req.body
        const secretAdminkey = process.env.ADMIN_KEY
        if (pin === secretAdminkey) {
            next()
        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid PIN2" });
        }
    }
    else {
     return res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing PIN in the request body" });
     } 
}

module.exports = { isAdmin };
```

and here is my controller code

```
const User = require("../schema/driver-schema")
const isLicenseNumberValid = require('../config/enum')
const { isAdmin } = require('../middleware/auth.js')

exports.registerAdmin= async function (req, res) {
    const { userName, password, email, pin } = req.body
    if (!userName || !password || !email || !pin) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing or incomplete data in the request body" });
    }
    if (!isAdmin(pin)) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Invalid PINs' });
    } 
    const newAdmin = new User ({
        userName, password, email, role: 'admin'
    })
    await newAdmin.save()
    if (newAdmin) {
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Admin account created successfully' });
    }
    else {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error creating admin account' });
    }
}
```

Please help me on how to solve this problem, almost a whole day spent googling and still stuck :(

Comment: `isAdmin` is a middleware, but you are using it like `isAdmin(pin)` - decide how to use it ^^

Comment: Thank you very much. This totally worked :) @moonwave99